# How to generate .NET DLL Library from Simulink and Stateflow

Tags: .net, matlab, dll, matlab-compiler, stateflow

How can Simulink and Stateflow models be compiled into a .NET shared DLL library? Is this a feature of Matlab? Is there a specific version or Matlab package required?

I am currently using Matlab 2017a on Windows 7. Any starting points would really be appreciated. Thank you.

Note: I asked this in a Matlab forum but did not receive any replies.
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/355348-how-to-generate-net-dll-library-from-simulink-and-stateflow

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked several times before, see for example:

- [Generate DLL from Simulink model](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/89263-generate-dll-from-simulink-model)
- [How to configure to generate DLL from SIMULINK and use the DLL](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/280984-how-to-configure-to-generate-dll-from-simulink-and-use-the-dll)
- [From Simulink to DLL - A tutorial](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9709-from-simulink-to-dll-a-tutorial)

In short, you need to use Embedded Coder with the Shared Library Target.

Comment: Is there a way of generating a managed library using Embedded Coder? I would like to use this within a .NET managed application (C#) without having to P/Invoke calls.